# Rails 5.1: How to override allowAction in rails-ujs to use a custom confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ujs

In versions of Rails previous to 5.1, which used `jquery_ujs`, we could replace the browser's confirmation popup with our own by overriding `$.rails.allowAction`, as explained [here](http://alexzerbach.com/use-sweet-alert-rails/).

As of Rails 5.1+, which uses `rails-ujs`, `$.rails.allowAction` is no longer available. How can we override Rails' default confirmation with our own in Rails 5 without having to switch back to `jquery_ujs`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same challenge and I looked a little bit more into it. What I found out along the way can be read here: https://medium.com/store2be-tech/how-to-use-sweetalert2-for-your-rails-5-1-rails-ujs-confirms-without-jquery-8a5b516b2a1

Here the final solution:

```
(function() {
  var handleConfirm = function(element) {
    if (!allowAction(this)) {
      Rails.stopEverything(element)
    }
  }

  var allowAction = function(element) {
    if (element.getAttribute('data-confirm-swal') === null) {
      return true
    }

    showConfirmationDialog(element)
    return false
  }

  // Display the confirmation dialog
  var showConfirmationDialog = function(element) {
    var message = element.getAttribute('data-confirm-swal')
    var text = element.getAttribute('data-text')

    swal({
      title: message || 'Are you sure?',
      text: text || '',
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    }).then(function(result) {
      confirmed(element, result)
    })
  }

  var confirmed = function(element, result) {
    if (result.value) {
      // User clicked confirm button
      element.removeAttribute('data-confirm-swal')
      element.click()
    }
  }

  // Hook the event before the other rails events so it works togeter
  // with `method: :delete`.
  // See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/start.coffee#L69
  document.addEventListener('rails:attachBindings', function(e) {
    Rails.delegate(document, 'a[data-confirm-swal]', 'click', handleConfirm)
  })

}).call(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a beautiful way to tweak into rails_ujs, so I came with with this workaround (using CoffeeScript):

```

```
$(document).on 'mousedown', 'a[data-confirm]', (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  link = $(e.target)

  message = link.data 'confirm'
  modal = $('.modal.confirmation')
  modal.find('.content').text(message)
  approve = modal.find('.approve')
  approve.attr('data-method', link.data('method'))
  approve.attr('href', link.attr('href'))

  modal.modal('show')
```

```

Mousedown event allows my event handler to be executed first (it goes before click event, which rails_ujs uses)

Answer (score 0):

You can override it with `Rails.confirm`, e.g. with CoffeeScript:

```coffee
Rails.confirm = (message, element) ->
  # your code
```

e.g. to have the confirm text show up for 2 seconds:

```coffee
WAITING_CLASS = "waiting-for-confirmation"
TIMEOUT = 2000

Rails.confirm = (message, element) ->
  if element.classList.contains(WAITING_CLASS)
    true
  else
    element.dataset.beforeConfirm = element.textContent
    element.textContent = element.dataset.confirm
    element.classList.add(WAITING_CLASS)

    timeout TIMEOUT, ->
      element.classList.remove(WAITING_CLASS)
      element.textContent = element.dataset.beforeConfirm

    false
```

See: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/confirm.coffee

And `timeout` and just a simple function that inverses the `setTimeout` parameters:

```js
var timeout = function(time, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, time)
}
```

Comment: Over time the rails team have change the name and signature of these methods so it'd pay to check the version of the code relevant to your Rails version before beginning to write your override. E.g. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.4.3/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/confirm.coffee